# How to show that the ith row $AB$ is the matrix product of the ith row of $A$ with the entire matrix $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider two matrices $A$ and $B$ of dimensions such that the product $AB$
exists. Show that the ith row of $AB$ is the matrix product of the ith row of
$A$ with the entire matrix $B$.

I am trying to use this definition $AB = \sum_{l=1}^{n} A_{il} B_{lk} = .$

Unfortunately I am stuck and need some help to proceed further.

Comment: $i$th row and $k$th column of $AB$ is $\sum_{l=1}^nA_{il}B_{lk}$ as you rightly said. Varying over $k$ just gives the whole row of $AB$ and we see that every entry of $B$ is used, while only the $i$th row of $A$ is used.

Comment: Maybe it helps to define a new row vector $a$ where $a_l = A_{i,l}$. That is, $a$ is the $i$-th row of $A$. Now write the product $aB$ and compare it to the $i$-th row of $AB$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a matrix $M$, define $M_{ij}$ to be its $(i,j)^{th}$ entry, and $M_i$ to be its $i^{th}$ row.

What you want to show is

> $$(AB)_i = A_iB$$

And by definition of the regular matrix multiplication,

> $$(AB)_{ij} = \sum A_{i\ell}B_{\ell j} \tag 1$$
>   $$(A_iB)_{1j} = \sum (A_i)_{1\ell}B_{\ell j} \tag 2$$

Since $A_iB$ has only one row, you'll just have to show that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equal for each $j$.

Comment: @I don't understand one thing. In (2), why does $A_{i}B$ has only one row?

Comment: So for a matrix $M$ with $m$ rows and $p$ columns and a matrix $N$ with $p$ rows and $n$ columns, their product $MN$ is defined and has $m$ rows and $n$ columns. Or, more briefly, if $M \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times p}$ and $N \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}$, we have $MN \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.

Comment: Since $A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times p}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}$ for some $p$ and $n$, we have $A_iB \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n}$, so $A_iB$ has one row.